# Typecasting a function parameter to an object from another class in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, breadth-first-search

I've been working on creating a bfs search algorithm on a 2D grid in Python (object-oriented). I have a Grid class that takes care of setting up the 2D grid and has some member functions to mark walls, start/end points, etc.

```
class Grid:

    def __init__(self, nodes=[]):
        self.nodes = nodes

    # Initializes a grid of rl x rc and fills all nodes with and empty value of 1
    def init_grid(self, rl, cl):
        arr = []
        arr2 = []
        for i in range(rl):
            for j in range(cl):
                arr2.append(Node("1", i, j))
            arr.append(arr2)
            arr2 = []
        self.nodes = arr

    # Sets the start and end points at the specified rows and cols
    def set_start_and_end(self, startr, startc, endr, endc):
        startNode = Node("S", startr, startc)
        endNode = Node("E", endr, endc)
        self.nodes[startr][startc] = startNode
        self.nodes[endr][endc] = endNode

    def mark_visited(self, row, col):
        self.nodes[row][col].val = "V"

    def mark_wall(self, row, col):
        self.nodes[row][col].val = "X"
```

I also have a file that will contain all my search algorithms (just BFS for now). In one of my helper functions for finding neighbours of a node, it takes in a node object as well as a grid object.

```
def get_neighbors(self, node, grid):
        neighbours = []

        R = len(grid)
        C = len(grid[0])

        dr = [-1, +1, 0, 0]
        dc = [0, 0, +1, -1]

        for i in range(4):
            rr = node.r + dr[i]
            cc = node.c + dc[i]

            if rr < 0 or cc < 0: continue
            if rr >= R or cc >= C: continue

            neighbour = grid[rr][cc]
            neighbours.append(neighbour)

        return neighbours
```

I'm new to Python, and come from typecast languages, but is there a way to typecast my node and grid objects in some way? As of right now I don't need to instantiate either the grid or node objects, but I'm not sure how to access them otherwise. Unless I'm just going about this the wrong way.

Comment: The concept of "casting' is not really useful in Python, although, informally people use it to mean "convert from one type to another". In Python, you create an object of a type by using the public API of that type, generally the constructor (or perhaps alternative constructors). What, **exactly** are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you mean you want to specify your method like this? That's possible in python and they're called type hints.
`def get_neighbours(self, node: Node, grid: Grid)`

Answer (score 0):

Your grid class functions depend on self so you must instantiate to access as it is now. 
If you want static behavior just put class attributes outside of your constructor:

```
class Grid():

    nodes = []
    def __init__(self):

    @staticmethod
    def init_grid(param1, param2):
        #Do stuff
        Grid.nodes = arr
```

Then in your other file `from filename import Grid`  and you should be able to access the static method with `Grid.init_grid()` and access nodes with `Grid.nodes`  If you can't, you can get an "static" object with `g_type = eval("Grid")` then you can access your "static" members with `g_type.init_grid()`

Hope that helps.